# How to generate HTML report with Mocha?

Tags: javascript

If anyone knows any examples for generating an html report in the Mocha framework, please share it. I have done googling and tried a lot but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 3):

You could give mochawesome a try which you can find here: https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome

I just tested it, really awesome results.

Comment: What does mochaawesome do differently?

Comment: With mochawesome I can start my tests automatically in the night (via node.js) and it will produce a nice looking html file until i get up.. pushed to my webserver.. That seems not to be possible with the standard html reporter as mentioned in the comment above (Calrion May 25 at 6:22) which says that the standard html reporter depends on browser usage.. which was my impression, too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code for mocha: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/tree/master/lib/reporters

It appears that there's a built-in HTML reporter. Have you tried running `mocha -R html`?

Comment: I  have same problem I tried `mocha -R html` but getting error `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/html.js:263
  var div = document.createElement('div');
            ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: plz seee this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794700/running-mocha-test-but-getting-error-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined

Comment: @geeks you may have an easier time reporting this to the mocha folks on github, t might be a bug

Comment: I recently received the same error, and my impression (given `document.createElement()` is a DOM function only available in a browser-like environment) was that the HTML reporter included in Mocha requires a browser and is unsuitable for generating HTML test output from a non-browser (e.g. Node.JS) environment.

Comment: @Calrion I suggest mentioning this on their issue tracker; the developers behind mocha should be able to confirm or deny that that is the case

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Allure reporter also integrates with Mocha tests. You can take a look at allure-mocha for more information.

I haven't used it though.